# Sugarcrm support for version 7

Tags: integration, sugarcrm

I have a zip file to upload in the module loader of sugarcrm..it works fine in version 6.5 but it does not work in version 7 and higher, it throws error...can anyone say what should be changed in order to support version 7? and what is the change from version 6 to 7 please help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed in SugarCRM 7 - what's the error you're seeing? What you need to change depends largely on what your install package does.

Your best starting point will be this: [Sugar Outfitters' Upgrading Your Modules for SugarCRM 7](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/blog/upgrading-your-modules-for-sugarcrm-7).